# Change the button text value dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the text value dynamically using this script.

I'v been trying to use a bunch of snipets for this but they don't return me the expected result.

```
document.theTimer.pause.value = "Close";
dialogBox.dialog({ modal: true, height: "75px" }, function(){ dialogbutton.val("Close")});
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-overlay">




        <div id="dialog-box"  >
            <div class="dialog-content" style=" overflow:hidden !important">
                <div id="dialog-message" style="color:#426bb3">
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="button" style="color:white" onclick="javascript: $('#dialog-box').dialog('close')">Annulla</a>
            </div>
            </div>


            </div>


 $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience", function () {

        var dialogBox = $("#dialog-box");
        var dialogbutton = $("#button");
        dialogBox.dialog({ modal: true, height: "75px" });
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
        $('#dialog-message').html("Preparando per il Download......");

        var req = $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
            successCallback: function (url) {

                dialogBox.dialog('close');

            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
                dialogBox.dialog('close');
                dialogBox.dialog({ modal: true, height: "75px" });
                dialogbutton.val("Chiudi");
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
                $('#dialog-message').html("<font color=\"red\"><b>Error Downloading file!</b></font>");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get button instance using `id` but it is `class`, so change

```
var dialogbutton = $("#button");
```

to

```
var dialogbutton = $(".button");
```

and use `.html()` to change the label instead of `.val()` because this is `a` tag and not `button`, so change below

```
dialogbutton.val("Chiudi");
```

to

```
dialogbutton.html("Chiudi");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#" class="button">Annulla</a>
```

Also, it is a `class`, so change here:

```
var dialogbutton = $(".button");
```

So please try this:

```
dialogbutton.text("Chiudi");
dialogbutton.html("Chiudi");
```

Instead of:

```
dialogbutton.val("Chiudi");
```

Comment: You should also recommand him to have a dom ready event because the javascript click event. `$(function(){ ... })`

Comment: @Sebastien.Beaulieu Sure man... But I guess he should be using in it.